# Easiest way to dual boot from 2 HDD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, multi-boot

I want to dual boot using my two hard drives. I have Windows 7 on one of them already, and I want to put SteamOS on the other.

I think all I have to do is create a SteamOS disk, remove the Windows hard drive, boot from the SteamOS disk with the blank hard drive in the computer, go through the installation process, and now I have one hard drive with SteamOS and another with Windows. Then I put the Windows hard drive back in alongside the SteamOS hard drive.

So after all of that, how would I tell my PC which OS to start up to? Would I have to enter the BIOS every time I start up, or is there a better way?

Answer (score -1):

There will be a special key which you press when the machine is booting which tells the BIOS to ask you to select the boot drive you want to use. But which key depends on which motherboard manufacturer. It may tell you at boot time which key to press.

These are the commonest keys, you can try them:
F8, F11, F12, ESC

Or if you let us know your motherboard we can probably tell you...